# scientific and mathematical use of 'tenet'

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In the Google dictionary, [***tenet***](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+tenet&oq=meaning+of+tenet&aqs=chrome..69i57.1736j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is defined as below.

> **tenet**
> a principle or belief, especially one of the main principles of a religion or philosophy.
> "*the tenets of a democratic society*"

After vewing through several example sentences including [Merriam Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenet), it seems like *tenet* is mostly used in the realms of  religions, politics, campaigns, or industries, not science.

Can it be used in science or math as well? For example, "*Newton's second law is one core tenet, which a bunch of other laws of motion or principles are derived from.*", or "*This equation is a tenet for other derivative equations.*".

Comment: Why not? You can see the definition. https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/412-describing-the-nature-of-science See the paragraph on curriculum fit. [The word Tenet brings up a man's name, too bad] [bunch of laws is informal]

Comment: @Lambie I've googled so, but most entries are about a science fiction movie, titled 'tenet'.

Comment: Plural is better. :) Look: https://sciencing.com/essential-tenets-scientific-method-8775195.html

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the link, but the use of 'tenet' in the paragraph is not in a strictly scientific way, as it states desired attitudes in dealing with science.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the second link. Aha, now I know it can be used in the general realm of science, but it seems like not in a scientific way itself.

I appreciate all your comments, and they have enlightened me a lot. However, now the point I am looking for is whether it can be used to mean core equations or laws in **physics** or **math**, e.g. *Newton's second law is a tenet for other subsidiary laws and equations*.

Comment: Science and math aren't about *beliefs*, they deal in *facts* and *theorems*. Why is it a surprise that something that means *core belief* is usually not used in science and math? Newton's second **law** or the Pythagorean **theorem** are not beliefs. You can't choose to believe that acceleration is directly proportional to mass instead of inversely proportional because division gives you a headache.

Comment: @ColleenV It says principle OR belief.

Comment: But you can believe something because the evidence suggests that it's true.  "Belief" doesn't have to mean "irrational belief", and I don't think "tenet" has to mean that either, so I think it's fair enough to use it to mean a theory that is believed because the evidence is in its favour.  I don't think "tenet" can mean "basis", though, so "tenet for other equations" won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In science and mathematics, an underlying statement which is assumed to be true, and serves as a starting point from which other statements are logically derived, is called an **axiom**. In considerations of Newton's three laws of motion, these are considered to be axioms:

> Axiom 1 (Newton’s first law of motion). As long as there is no
> external action, a particle’s velocity will remain constant.
>
> Axiom 2 (Newton’s second law of motion). If there is a net force
> acting on a particle, then its instantaneous change in momentum due to
> that force is equal to that force:
>
> Axiom 3 (Newton’s third law of motion). If a body exerts a force F1 on
> a second body, the second body exerts an equal but opposite force F2,
> on the first.

Timon Idema - Associate Professor (Bionanoscience) at Delft University of Technology

[Newton's Laws of Motion (Physics Libretexts)](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Mechanics_and_Relativity_(Idema)/02%3A_Forces/2.01%3A_Newton%27s_Laws_of_Motion)

[Axiom (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/axiom)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used in science when describing theories, and is quite commonly used to describe the [principles of evolution by natural selection](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22tenets%22%20of%20evolutionary%20theory&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).

It is not so commonly used in the 'harder' sciences and not at all when talking about mathematical theorems.